# C# running PowerShell (BeginInvoke) trying to Copy-Item : ACCESS DENIED

Tags: c#, powershell

User: A who is an ADMIN (or has rights) runs C#-IIS app, which, runs PowerShell (through new PowerShell.Create(), Script() and ps.BeginInvoke).

PS script does a Copy-Item from one local folder to a networked folder (user has rights). In fact, for testing, I set 'Everyone' to have rights (so it's likely not IIS_IUSRS either).

### Result: "Access is denied" error.

How can I solve this?

Background:

1. Cannot explicitly run the powershell exe elevated because I need to capture verbose and other output streams asynchronously.
2. Just for fun - tried the using (new Impersonator(...)) {...}. But as expected, I'm already running as myself/admin - no change.
3. When I dump the username (Write-Verbose "Running as $env:username") - I get the machine name (with dollar sign following) - if that helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Bit out of my depth here, but could this be due to the limitation on impersonation: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are running IIS 7.5.  To me, it sounds like the application pool is running with Identity set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.  Changing it to `NetworkService` (or an explicit domain account) should do the trick.

From IIS Manager, go to Application Pools, determine which App Pool is hosting your site, right-click, and select "Advanced Settings."  You'll find Identity under the **Process Model** section.

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. Since I allowed 'Everyone' for both directories - I would have been surprised if this worked. Thanks tho.

Comment: what to do to know who will run the process?